# Разбор стека. Удаление повторов

Tags: алгоритм, коллекции

Подскажите пожалуйста, как имея стек (самописный) получить из него новый, без повторяющихся элементов? Можно использовать, естественно, вспомогательные стеки. На ум приходит только модификация ханойской башни и всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Заводите множество (самописное или нет, как хотите).
2. Перекладываете данные в новый стек, занося их ещё и во множество. Если данное уже есть во множестве, в новый стек не кладёте.
3. Разбираете новый стек, перекладывая данные в исходный стек, таким образом вы их снова разворачиваете.

---

В случае, когда дополнительными структурами данных (кроме одного дополнительного стека) пользоваться нельзя, подойдёт следующая идея. Назовём *просмотром с удалением* такую операцию:

1. Элементы перекладываются из 1-го стека во второй
2. Если по пути встречается удаляемый элемент (начиная с некоторого места), он не кладётся во второй стек
3. Данные перекладываются назад

Тогда делаем так: проводим просмотр с удалением элементов после 1-го, равных этому самому первому. Затем то же для второго элемента и т. д., до конца стека. Это медленно, но ведёт к цели, т. к. после `i`-ого просмотра первые `i` элементов стека уникальны.

Comment: Собственно это идея уже была мной реализована( с помощью set в c++ ), но преподаватель сказал, что использовать какие-либо контейнеры нельзя. Только стеки.

Так же он сказал очень интересную вещь: задачу, скорее всего, можно решить всего-то двумя стеками, но идею не рассказал.

Comment: @kvendingoldo: Ну, если не `std::set`, то самописный линейный список покатит. Проблема в том, чтобы выяснить, встречался ли элемент раньше. Без этого никак по идее.

Comment: @kvendingoldo: Подождите-ка. А может повторяющиеся элементы идут _подряд_? Тогда всё становится проще.

Comment: Нет, повторяющиеся элементы лежат в стеке хаотично.

Comment: Т.е. решить задачу без какой-либо другой структуры данных невозможно? За идею с линейным списком - спасибо, думаю пойдет.

Comment: @kvendingoldo: Ну, можно сделать по-идиотски, но будет работать. Нужно два стека и парочка дополнительных переменных. Идея такая. Можно переложить элементы в другой стек и назад, пусть это называется операция Х.

Comment: @kvendingoldo: Делаем вот что. Выполняем операцию Х, запоминаем 1-ый элемент в доп. переменную. Если он встретился по дороге, не копируем его. После этого у нас точно не повторяется первый элемент.

Comment: @kvendingoldo: Затем то же самое со вторым элементом и т. д. Нужен счётчик, чтобы помнить, какой элемент мы сейчас проверяем.

Comment: Идея с двумя переменными это же, по сути, "вычеркивание" неугодных нам элементов? Вроде, такой алгоритм будет оооочень медленно работать.

Но предложенные идеи понял - спасибо :) Буду реализовывать.

Comment: @kvendingoldo: Жуууутко медленно. В худшем случае столько проходов, сколько элементов в стеке. Но зато всего два стека, да

Answer (score 1):

1. Если одинаковые элементы в стеке лежат рядом, то задача решается элементарно
2. Если одинаковые элементы лежат не рядом, то нужно сначала нужно стек отсортировать. Для этого можно воспользоваться алгоритмом сортировки, который работает только при сравнении двух рядом лежащих переменных (потому что мы можем получить их, два раза сделав pop). Например, сортировка пузырьком удовлетворяет таким требованиям. Результат сортировки соответственно записываем в другой стек на каждой итерации

Comment: Сортировать стек? Лолшто? :)

Comment: @VladD А то! На самом деле примерно то же, что и ты предлагаешь.

Comment: Ну, нам же надо не разрушить исходный порядок ещё.

Comment: @VladD, не было такого условия

Comment: Вообще да, нужен исходный порядок элементов, но это не сильно обязательно.

Comment: @Lol4t0: А, я понял, как сделать один проход пузырька при перекладывании. Мегаизврат, +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[7,5,4,7,8,7,3];

A: for(var b=[], c=[]; a.length; [b,c]=[c,b]) {
  let x = a.pop();

  while(b.length) {
    let y = b.pop();
    c.push(y);

    if(x===y) {
      while(b.length) {
        c.push(b.pop());
      }

      continue A;
    }
  }

  c.push(x);
}

console.log(b);
```